# How to rebase on a new version of a cherry picked parent

Tags: git, git-rebase, gerrit

Consider the highlighted commits in the following :

[image: GITK]

For the current discussion I'll refer to the commits as follows :
Commit 1 : Read Language settings from the User Settings
Commit 2 : [POC] Do not review

We use Gerrit for code review. Both Commit 1 and Commit 2 are under review and have not been merged.  I am working on Commit 1 which required code in Commit 2 and hence had to be based off it. These are the commands I used :

1. Cherry Pick Commit 2. I use the cherry-pick command that get from Gerrit for that change:
   [image: Cherry-pick Commit 2]
2. Make the changes that were needed for my work and push a change which became Commit 1. When I first pushed Commit 1, it was based on patchset 8 of Commit 2.

As and when I get review comments on my commit (Commit 1), I push new patch sets for it on Gerrit. However, when it is to be merged finally, it needs to be on the latest patchset of it's parent (Commit 2). The way I do it now is as follows :

1. git checkout working2
2. git reset --hard remotes/origin/head
3. Cherry-pick Commit 2  ---> This gets me the latest version of Commit 2
4. Cherry-pick Commit 1
5. git push origin working2:refs/for/head

Is there a way in which I can just get the latest patchset of Commit 2 without doing all of the above ? Perhaps some kind of interactive cherry pick or rebase ?

Comment: From where do you get the latest version of Commit 2? From origin?

Comment: Commit 2 has various 'patch sets' .. and the latest version of Commit 2 means the last submitted patchset. The command to get a specific patchset is as follows :

git fetch ssh://user@gerrit.dev.xyz.net:29418/management-console refs/changes/26/11926/11 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply rebase Commit 1 to the FETCH_HEAD. While on working2 branch,

```
$ git fetch ssh://user@gerrit.dev.xyz.net:29418/management-console refs/changes/26/11926/11 
$ git rebase -i FETCH_HEAD
```

Remove the line with the commit message of Commit 2 (first line usually). Now Commit 1 will be on top of the latest Commit 2. If you're unfamiliar with interactive rebase, take a look  [here](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/12/10/git-interactive-rebase-tips/).

Comment: This works !! Could you please explain what the following command does ?

git fetch ssh://user@gerrit.dev.xyz.net:29418/management-console refs/changes/26/11926/11 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD

Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect. The first command fetches the specific patchset so that it's in remotes/origin/master and this commit is marked with a FETCH_HEAD pointer ? Subsequently, one can do an interactive rebase using this pointer ? Is that what happens ?

Thanks !!

Comment: `git fetch` only _fetches_ the changes from the remote which are then stored in FETCH_HEAD; the new changes do not come to a branch. 

When you `git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD` you are creating a copy of this latest commit in your current branch.
Yes, actually what we've done is to rebase Commit 1 on top of this new FETCH_HEAD.